# CheckErr(err) function crashing in golang

Tags: go

If I run this code everything works fine and nothing is apparently wrong in the end result (the right id is being printed).

```
stmt, err := db.Conn.Prepare("INSERT INTO tablename a VALUES (?)")
CheckErr(err)
defer stmt.Close()
res, err := stmt.Exec(&t.Id)
CheckErr(err)

id, err := res.LastInsertId()
fmt.Println(id)
```

But when I add another `CheckErr(err)` at the end and I run, I get this:

```
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

This is the first thing in the stack trace after the panics:

```
id, err := res.LastInsertId()
```

And no id is printed, which is weird since the println comes before the new CheckErr(err)

Any idea why this is happening? I'm clueless

```
func CheckErr(err error) {
  if err != nil {
    raven.CaptureErrorAndWait(err, nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `CheckErr`?

Comment: I actually assumed it was a built in function since I'm building on someone else's code and I'm new to go. I've edited the OP

Comment: It looks like the application is reporting errors, but not handling them. 
 If `stmt.Exec(&t.Id)` returns a nil result and an error, then the program will continue executing to the call to `LastInsertId` and panic.

Comment: I just removed all error checking to test. I printed res and err from exec, and indeed res is nil and err says couldn't add the rows, and then LastInsertId crashes. But if I don't print those two things, it works and the correct ID is returned from LastInserId. I'm really lost here

Comment: Probably not that, doesn't make sense. I'll keep looking. Thanks for the help

Comment: As I noted in a comment and somebody else noted in an answer,  the program continues execution after an error.  The application should handle errors in some way. `CheckErr` does not handle errors, it just reports them with raven.

Comment: I assume I should add panic(err) to it or something?

Comment: `panic` when you want your program to crash, otherwise handle the error appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CheckErr(err)` does not exit or return if `err != nil`. The program will continue to execute to `id, err := res.LastInsertId()` and panic if `res` is nil.